# getting a 'No reducer provided for key "auth"' error using configurestore in redux-toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

Getting the 'No reducer provided for key "auth"' error, think it's to do with how I'm passing it to the store from the slice. Everything is working fine apart from the No reducer error.
Should I use a rootReducer ? Looked through the documentation but just drawing a blank

the store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import alertReducer from '../features/alerts/alertSlice';
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    alert: alertReducer,
    auth: authReducer
  },
});
```

the authslice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import api from '../../utils/api';
import { setAlert } from '../alerts/alertSlice';

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    registerSuccess: (state, action) => {
      const { payload } = action.payload;
      state.push({
        payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
      });
    },
    registerFail: (state) => {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      state.token = null;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});

const { registerSuccess, registerFail } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;

// Register User
export const register = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.post('/users', formData);

    dispatch(registerSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch(registerFail());
  }
};
```

No reducer error stack

```
No reducer provided for key "auth" vendors~main.chunk.js:36893:20
    e http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:36893
    warning http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:45798
    combineReducers http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:45882
    configureStore http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:1121
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:320
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:400
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:852
    fn http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1965
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2071
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:852
    fn http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1194
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1324
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:852
    fn http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:895
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1177
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:852
    fn http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:137
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:297
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:852
    fn http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1843
    js http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1950
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:852
    fn http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151
    1 http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2085
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:852
    checkDeferredModules http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46
    webpackJsonpCallback http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: Show the full error stack

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake of not importing {registerSuccess,registerFail} in Front end

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).